# Is possible to have 2 node.js instances that points to the same host:port but different url?

Tags: node.js, url, routes

Is possible to have 2 node.js instances that points to localhost:8080 but instance 1 handles all requests that arrive to localhost:8080/instance1 and instance 2 to localhost:8080/instance2?

Answer (score 0):

That sounds like the [stagecoach](http://justjs.com/posts/deploying-node-js-and-mongodb-in-production-with-stagecoach) way to serve node. It uses nodejitsu's [node-http-proxy](https://github.com/nodejitsu/node-http-proxy/)